# how to have database offline for iOS app

Tags: ios7

I would like to develop dictionary app for iOS application. and I am not sure which database Managment system should I use to store data. I want to my app to be offline so even user that don't have internet, they still can use my app. so my question which database should I use to store my database ? I research on google, it said sqlite. so if i store my data in sqlite so will my data in database sqllite will go with my app? thank

Comment: How complete will this dictionary be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sqlite is your DB of choice unless you're just working with a couple of dozen records.
If you plan to use CoreData, you can also address sqlite with it.

If you don't plan to use CoreData, you can still use sqlite and work directly with the DB. There are good wrappers which help you, like FMDB: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb